# Android: Erro ao executar aplicação

Tags: java, android, construtor, logcat

Notei que usando o atalho <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> e selecionando para ele me dar os construtores, ele tenta criar um construtor com cada propriedade `private` (cManager e mTextView). Lembro que já criei projetos sem isso e funcionaram corretamente.

O erro acontece quando executo a aplicação, segue o logcat completo e o construtor da página:

Construtor com propriedades privadas:

```
    private ConnectivityManager cManager;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public SplashScreenActivity() {
        this.cManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        this.mTextView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.mProgressText);
    }
```

LogCat:

```
02-20 18:20:56.155    1591-1591/com.universo91.towersrock I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-20 18:20:58.355    1591-1591/com.universo91.towersrock D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
02-20 18:20:58.361    1591-1591/com.universo91.towersrock E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.universo91.towersrock, PID: 1591
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.universo91.towersrock/com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity has no zero argument constructor
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity has no zero argument constructor
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1563)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-20 18:20:58.772    1591-1603/com.universo91.towersrock I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1747(114KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 391KB/623KB, paused 825us total 382.655ms
02-20 18:21:29.824    1690-1690/com.universo91.towersrock D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-20 18:21:29.829    1690-1690/com.universo91.towersrock E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.universo91.towersrock, PID: 1690
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.universo91.towersrock/com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity has no zero argument constructor
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity has no zero argument constructor
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1563)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-20 18:21:30.168    1690-1702/com.universo91.towersrock I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1749(114KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 391KB/623KB, paused 856us total 166.355ms
02-20 18:21:53.341    1690-1690/com.universo91.towersrock I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1690 SIG: 9
02-20 18:26:00.878    1754-1754/com.universo91.towersrock D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-20 18:26:00.903    1754-1754/com.universo91.towersrock E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.universo91.towersrock, PID: 1754
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.universo91.towersrock/com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
            at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4989)
            at com.universo91.towersrock.Pages.SplashScreenActivity.<init>(SplashScreenActivity.java:24)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-20 18:26:01.144    1754-1766/com.universo91.towersrock I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1745(118KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 382KB/623KB, paused 950us total 131.218ms
02-20 18:26:04.429    1754-1754/com.universo91.towersrock I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1754 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Poderia incluir o código da `SplashScreenActivity`? O erro é que você está acessando serviços antes do método `onCreate` ser chamado. O certo para acessar recursos da `Activity` é após a chamada do `super.onCreate` e para elementos do layout, após o `setContentView`.

Comment: coloque como resposta, eu resolvi o problema assim.

Answer (score 3):

O erro é que você está acessando serviços do sistema antes do método `super.onCreate` ser chamado. E consequentemente a `Activity` não foi criada por completo.

O certo para acessar recursos do sistema, é após a chamada do `super.onCreate()` e para elementos do layout, após o `setContentView`.